# Add custom client to Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer;

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I am using the asp.net core SPA template with identity to create a react SPA with a web api backend. Authentication is provided by a wrapper for Identity Server 4 [Wrapper](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/8f508e70842e67839cdedbd8208aba46ebf55f32/src/Identity/ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer). This wrapper provides a couple of useful config profiles [Config docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#other-configuration-options). These are really useful for getting my SPA to work out of the box. It seems that any other config to define possible clients that is not in the supported docs is ignored and not passed down to the underlying Identify server. [Wrapper config builder](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/8f508e70842e67839cdedbd8208aba46ebf55f32/src/Identity/ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer/src/Configuration/ConfigureClients.cs#L60)

I would really like to be able to use the config and integrations provided by the asp.net core identity library but also be able to provide my own clients defined in the appsettings.json. This is so I can add another client to the identity server for a mobile application.

You can create the same template i am using with this line.

```
dotnet new react -o <output_directory_name> -au Individual
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.